# Chrome Extension Manifest permissions for same domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just got a strange issue about the permission of the chrome extension.
For the same domain, I can access some URLs but can't access another URL.

Below is part of manifest.json.

`"permissions": ["storage"],`
`"host_permissions": ["*://*.domain.com/*"],`
`"content_scripts": [{`
`"js": ["js/content.js"],`
`"css": ["css/main.css"],`
`"matches": ["*://*.domain.com/*"],`
`"run_at": "document_idle",`
`"all_frames": true`
}]

https://dev.domain.com/tech works good but https://dev.domain.com/new doesn't work.

I can't know the correct reason. If someone knows the above issue, plz help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to show how you acces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting "match_about_blank": true on the manifest file.
By default, an extension can't access the blank iframe content.
It's the reason why I can't access different URLs on the same domain.